# Bootstrap Modals (and other functions) work on localhost but not heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a site that works fine on localhost but is having issues on Heroku.

I have some modals and an accordion that both function as expected on localhost, but simply don't work on Heroku for production.

The only error I can see is a console error that shows up on Heroku saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "@hotwired/turbo-rails". Relative references must start with either
> "/", "./", or "../".

Here's an example of a modal:
<button type="

```
button" class="btn btn-black-outline" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#newProductModal">
      Add a New Product
    </button>
<div class="modal fade" id="newProductModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="newProductModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="newProductModalLabel">Add a New Product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <%= render partial: "products/modal_innards", locals: { product: product } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Here's the accordion:

```
                <div class="accordion mb-5" id="accordionKits">
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h3 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne1"><button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                            What shrouds (radiator plastic) does the Aloop kit use?
                        </button></h3>
                        <div class="accordion-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne1" aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-bs-parent="#accordionKits">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                The Aloop 4SMX seat/tank kit uses shrouds from the 1999 CR250 Honda. Currently we are supplying Acerbis brand shrouds with our kits, but you could also use genuine Honda shrouds, or even UFO or some other brand. Any shrouds meant to fit the 1999 CR250 should fit our kit. We do modify the shrouds slightly to fit our tank though. Basically the mods consist of cutting off the rear shroud bolt hole and mount, and removing the vertical reinforcing rib on the inside of the shroud. If you're fitting your own replacement shrouds use your original Aloop shroud as a guide.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    .... (more items) ....
                </div>
```

I've asked the almighty GPT and searched SO, but I can't seem to find an answer.  Anyone have any troubleshooting ideas?